# Problem with trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

I am having trouble solving this equation

$$4\cdot \sin \theta + 2 \cdot \sin 2\theta =5$$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I tried graphing it but cant then tried taking a common factor just do not know where to start

Comment: Are you trying to solve analytically or numerically?

Comment: That problem looks pretty tough to solve analytically to me. Where did you come across it?

Comment: past Intenational Bacculureate exam

Answer (score 2):

If you put $t=\tan \frac {\theta}2$ you obtain $$4\cdot\sin \theta+4\cdot \sin \theta\cdot\cos\theta=4\left(\frac {2t}{1+t^2}\right)\left(1+\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\right)=5$$

Multiply though by $(1+t^2)^2$ to obtain $$16t=5(1+t^2)^2$$From which it is clear that any solution has $t$ positive (rhs is positive), and a quick sketch graph shows there will be two solutions.

$t=0, 16t=0, 5(1+t^2)^2=5\gt 0$

$t=.5, 16t=8, 5(1+t^2)^2=\frac {125}{16}\lt 8$

$t=1, 16t=16, 5(1+t^2)^2=20\gt 16$

So there is one solution for $t$ in $(0,0.5)$ and another in $(0.5,1)$

The equation can be rewritten as a quartic $$5t^4+10t^2-16t+5=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Analytically this is almost impossible. Let me explain why:
I started writing $\sin(2x) = 2\cos(x)\sin(x)$ which gave the following equation after factorising :
$$\sin(x)\big(1+\cos(x)\big) = \frac54$$
Now, letting $\cos(x) = \sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}$ and after taking out the square root, I obtained :
$$\bigg(\frac5{4\sin(x)} - 1\bigg)^2 = 1-\sin^2(x)$$

Expand out and substituting $X = \sin(x)$ you obtain the following equation to solve :
$$X^4 - \frac{5X}{2} + \frac{25}{16} = 0$$

A quartic equation. It is well known that they have a general solution but it is so complicated I'd rather [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4%20-%2010x/4%2b25/16%20=%200) do it for me.
Solutions are the inverse sine of them.

From my point of view, there is no easy way to write down the solution, perhaps numerical solution is better in this case. Unless I'm missing an obvious trick...

Comment: how do i get a numerical solution

Comment: There are many ways to do this. Newton-Raphson method is a good one. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method

Comment: Remember that it doesn't describe all solutions. You also want to include an equation in which $\cos x = -\sqrt{1-sin^2(x)}$

Comment: @EricAm : It is not necessary is I am squaring it after to get rid of the square root. So $\pm$ becomes $+$ again.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
4\sin \theta+2\sin 2\theta&=5\\
4\sin \theta+2\cdot2\sin \theta\cos\theta&=5\\
4\sin \theta+4\sin \theta\cos\theta&=5\\
4\sin \theta(1+\cos\theta)&=5
\end{align}
Take square both sides.
\begin{align}
4^2\sin^2 \theta(1+\cos\theta)^2&=5^2\\
16(1-\cos^2\theta)(1+\cos\theta)^2&=25
\end{align}
Let $x=\cos\theta$.
\begin{align}
16(1-x^2)(1+x)^2&=25\\
x^4+2x^3-2x-1&=-\frac{25}{16}\\
x^4+2x^3-2x&=-\frac{9}{16}\\
16x^4+32x^3-32x+9&=0
\end{align}